# How do I query exchange for all events on a calendar?

Tags: asp.net, jquery, calendar, exchange-server

I'm currently writing a room booking diary template for an ASP .Net CMS and I need to be able to retrieve the information from an exchange calendar.

Can anyone point me in the direction of some good sample code which lets me query an individual calendar based on a month parameter? Also, is it possible to provide a parameter to the query to either include or exclude those appointments / meetings which are only tentatively agreed?

Finally, are there any good jQuery based calendar plugins which are ie6 compatible for when I wish to display the resulting information?

Thanks a lot,

Brian.

Comment: You should probably split your jQuery question into a separate question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your jQuery based calendar I would use [FullCalendar](http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/)

It works with: Firefox 2/3, Safari 3/4, Opera 10, IE 6/7/8